# Traversing to the element closest to the element clicked jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, coffeescript, traversal

I have this kind of setup in my html

```
<section class="grp">
  <ul class="normal">
    <li>Normal Thing <button class="toggle-advanced">toggle advanced</button></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="advanced">
    <li>This is Advanced</li>
  </ul>
</section>
<h1>Another Thing</h1>
<section class="grp">
  <ul class="normal">
    <li>Normal Thing <button class="toggle-advanced">toggle advanced</button></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="advanced">
    <li>This is Advanced</li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

How can I toggle the "advanced" `ul` if I clicked the button in `ul.normal`?

I tried it like this in coffeescript

```
$('.normal').on 'click', '.toggle-advanced', (e) ->
  $(@).closest('.grp').siblings('.advanced').slideToggle();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since jquery is tagged... using jquery

```
$('.toggle-advanced').click(function(){
    $(this).parents('ul.normal').siblings('ul.advanced').toggle();
});
```

or

```
$('.toggle-advanced').click(function(){
    $(this).parents('.grp').find('ul.advanced').toggle();
});
```

these should work unless you aree adding the content dynamically.. use `on()` if added dynamically

```
$('.normal').on('click', '.toggle-advanced', function(){
   $(this).parents('.grp').find('ul.advanced').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`.advanced` is not a sibling of `.grp` element, it is the sibling of the parent `.normal` element

```
$(@).closest('.normal').siblings('.advanced').slideToggle();
```

The javascript equal will be

```
$('.normal').on('click', '.toggle-advanced', function(){
    $(this).closest('.normal').siblings('.advanced').slideToggle();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
$(".toggle-advanced").on('click', function(){

    $(this).closest(".normal").siblings('.advanced').slideToggle();

});
```

this code is jquery based

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
$("ul.normal>li>button").click(function () {
   $(this).closest('.normal').siblings('.advanced').slideToggle();
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/riri78/dQcFE/

Comment: If i clicked anything in the ul it toggles.., the toggle must be coming from the button

Answer (score 1):

In Jquery, you can use **parent** and **siblings** functions to get to the desired element.

Try this:

```
$('.toggle-advanced').click(function() {
  $('this').parent().siblings().toggleSomething()
});
```

**siblings** returns all the siblings for given element, which in your case will always return "advanced" ul.